# Reference about product of elliptic curves

Tags: reference-request, elliptic-curves, products

I am wondering if there is some accessible reference to learn about product of elliptic curves and their 'properties'. For *dimension* 1, there is plenty to find. I think the dimension 2 case is done as follows:

Start with an elliptic curve over a field $K$, given by
$$f(X,Y)=Y^2+a_1XY+a_3Y-X^3-a_2X^2-a_4X-a_6=0.$$
We know how the coordinate ring $K[E]$ and the funcion field on $E$ are defined. Now I would like to define, for instance, the coordinate ring on $E\times E$. This would be just
$$\frac{K[X_1,Y_1,X_2,Y_2]}{(f(X_1,Y_1),f(X_2,Y_2))},$$
I assume.

Comment: What about products of elliptic curves would you like to find out?

Comment: Good question. I would like to understand some properties on  $K(E^n)$,  the funcion field on $E^n$. The divisor of an element of $K(E^n)$, ...

Answer (score 2):

Answered by comment from QiL.

> You only get affine parts of an elliptic curve and of products of elliptic curves. The function field of $E^n$ is just $K(E)\otimes_K ...\otimes_K K(E)$